# How Angular type checking works

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm interested in several scenarios.

1. Let's say I have a http call which fetches all movies from my php back-end api. As you know this is observable. and I have to subscribe.

   ```
    // this is my service
    getAll() : Observable<Movie[]>{
       this.http.get("/movies");
    }

    // in my component I subscribe this 
    getMovies(){
       this.movieService.getAll().subscribe(movies=>{
          this.movies = movies; //I probably have this.movies as any or Movie[] type
       })
     }
   ```

The question is, why would I need to write `Observable<Movie[]>` as the return type for `getAll() function` in my service as I showed you? I could just write `getAll()` and didn't specify `return type` or specify `Observable<any>.` but I did the type as `Movie[]`. What advantages does it bring me? I understand in `getAll() function`, it just returns observable and cast it to `Observable<Movie[]>`.

Comment: I understand it the same way, you are forcing an implicit conversion to `Movie[]` and this type will propagate into `this.movies` later. Explicit types can help the compiler in rising useful error/debug messages.

Comment: It's only to help you to write consistent code in "typescript editor", really Angular don't check if your received object is of type movie or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All in all Typescript and using types is just to support you development with type checks and autocompletion. When you specify no return type on a function and use this function, your IDE won't tell you a thing about what type you can expect as a return value. Also the typescript compiler won't complain when you mess things up.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
class Movies {
  title: string;
  length: number;
  genre: string;
}    

getAll(): Observable<any>
```

You can now do things like:

```
getAll().subscribe(m => {
  // name is not a property of movie
  console.log(m.name);
});
```

Your code will compile and run, but you will see undefined on your console.

If you had defined your function like this:

```
getAll(): Observable<Movie>
```

Your IDE would show you an error, complaing name is not a property of Movie, because the typescript compiler knows you used a wrong property. Also it would give you autocomplete and suggest all properties which are available.

Using Typescript without type definitions is more or less like using plain Javascript. Using it with type definitions gives you support in autocompletion and errors when you do something wrong.

Eventually typescript gets compiled to javascript and the browser doesn't care about types but during development inside an IDE it could be a great help.

Comment: Thanks so much. so writing types as any most of the time might not be the good idea. and I should be creating models (interfaces) for all kind of data I get from http back-end api.

Comment: It is good practice to write model classes or interfaces, especially for data you get from your backend api. But you should also use models for every kind of objects you share across your application, otherwise you have no autocomplete or error notifications from typescript. When to use interface or class is well explained in this articel: https://toddmotto.com/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript